# getWidth() & getHeight() returning 0 inside RecyclerView/Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm calling the populating method for the `RecyclerView` inside the `OnCreateView` method in several fragments, they are then directed to the adapter for which populates the feeds (depending on the `context` of the `Fragment`).

At the minute, I am adding tags to an uploaded image from a user on the feed. Those tags require an `x` and `y` value (position), in which is a percentage of the container (which is set and saved to a BaaS when they upload). At the moment, the pixel to percentage formula works perfectly but when I try and grab the dimensions of the container, every option I have tried `returns 0` every time.

```
RecyclerViewHolderAllFeeds(View view) {
    ...
    this.imageContainer = (RelativeLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.image_container);
}
```

Tag Snippet: 
(This function is called inside the bind, to bind all the tags to the uploaded image)

```
  float x = containerWidth - Float.parseFloat(model.getXpoints(o)) / 100 * containerWidth;
            float y = containerHeight - Float.parseFloat(model.getYpoints(o)) / 100 * containerHeight;
            Log.e("measuredWidth", "" + containerHeight + "" + containerWidth);
            Log.e("getPointX", "" + model.getXpoints(o) + "" + model.getYpoints(o));
            Log.e("x", "x" + x + "y" + y);
            tag.setX(x);
            tag.setY(y);
```

I set the values for containerWidth at the moment in the OnCreateViewHolder method:

```
RecyclerViewHolderAllFeeds holder = null;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
    if (viewType == 1) {
        // This method will inflate the custom layout and return as viewholde
        ViewGroup mainGroup = (ViewGroup) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_and_search_feed_item_row, viewGroup, false);
        holder =  new RecyclerViewHolderAllFeeds(mainGroup);
        containerWidth = getContainerWidth(holder);
        containerHeight = getContainerHeight(holder);
    } else {
        ViewGroup mainGroup = (ViewGroup) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_item, viewGroup, false);
        holder =  new ProgressViewHolder(mainGroup);
    }
    return  holder;
```

I have also tried this way inside the `onViewAttchedToWindow` method:

```
   @Override
   public void onViewAttachedToWindow(RecyclerViewHolderAllFeeds holder) {
       super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
       containerWidth = getContainerWidth(holder);
       containerHeight = getContainerHeight(holder);
   }
```

But again `x` and `y` values equate to zero.

GetContainerWidth(ViewHolder holder) method:

```
 float getContainerWidth(final RecyclerViewHolderAllFeeds h) {
        final int[] width = new int[1];
        final ViewTreeObserver observer = h.imageContainer.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                width[0] = h.imageContainer.getWidth();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    h.imageContainer.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    h.imageContainer.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }
            }
        });
        return width[0];
    }
```

the same logic is applied to the `getContainerHeight(ViewHolder holder)` method.

I have also tried it without a global listener on the tree observer and with a listener on the preDraw parameters.

```
observer.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                height[0] = h.imageContainer.getHeight();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    h.imageContainer.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Log:

> E/measuredWidth&Height: 0.0 0.0 
>   E/getPointX&Y: 70.13 88.00 
>   E/x: x 0.0 y 0.0

Could there be a work around in regards to initializing the layout somewhere else and gathering the information and storing it somewhere? I've exhausted plenty of options. I just feel I haven't seen enough around `Fragments` and `RecyclerViews` within the SO community.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `addOnGlobalLayoutListener` does not execute in linear, you need to wait its callback.

Comment: But the callback returns too late for when I need the height and width (after the ViewHolder has been binded for the first few items) Would you recommend anything else?

Comment: You need to execute your math logic inside the callback and thats is also the only place you can manipulate the view (if necessary).

Comment: Of course i do. Okay, I'll have a look and let you know.

Comment: didn't work, it looks like i'll have to find another way around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As **@Enzokie** mentioned you have to calculate your `x` and `y` inside callback after you will know width and height of your `imageContainer`. So all you need is to move your `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to `onBindViewHolder` method, like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolderAllFeeds h, int position) {
    ...
    final ViewTreeObserver observer = h.imageContainer.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                h.imageContainer.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                h.imageContainer.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }

            int containerWidth = h.imageContainer.getWidth();
            int containerHeight = h.imageContainer.getHeight();
            float x = containerWidth - Float.parseFloat(model.getXpoints(o)) / 100 * containerWidth;
            float y = containerHeight - Float.parseFloat(model.getYpoints(o)) / 100 * containerHeight;
            Log.e("measuredWidth", "" + containerHeight + "" + containerWidth);
            Log.e("getPointX", "" + model.getXpoints(o) + "" + model.getYpoints(o));
            Log.e("x", "x" + x + "y" + y);

            h.tag.setX(x);
            h.tag.setY(y);
            h.tag.requestLayout();
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, I will certainly test this out.

Comment: And looking forward to your bounty :)

Comment: sorry buddy totally forgot to click it.