# RecyclerView width is sometimes zero (not deterministic)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

We have detected this issue that should be happening only under some specific circumstances or maybe because of a race condition. Is not reproduceable, so we only have some evidences at logs.

In the app there's a `Fragment` which contains a `RecyclerView` and sometimes it's completely blank.

The content is being loaded in a background thread and the adapter is being refreshed after that, on the UI-thread. But the width of the `RecyclerView` is zero. So, no content is shown at all.

This is how I initialize the list:

```
private void initList() {
    final int numberOfPreviewColumns = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.view_files_num_columns);

    fileAdapter = initializeAdapter(numberOfPreviewColumns);
    fileAdapter.setChoiceMode(getDefaultChoiceMode());

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    // By posting to the RecyclerView the runnable is executed AFTER(!) the view has been drawn
    recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int width = recyclerView.getWidth();
            if (width <= 0) {
                CriticalLogger.error("Error trying to set width to fileAdapter in FileManagerFragment: " + width);
            }
        }
    });

    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), numberOfPreviewColumns) {
        @Override
        protected int getExtraLayoutSpace(State state) {
            try {
                return SplitTest.ExtraLayoutSpaceSize.getValueOrMiddleDefault();
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    };

    layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int i) {
            return fileAdapter.shouldDivideInColumns() ? 1 : numberOfPreviewColumns;
        }
    });

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(fileAdapter);
}
```

The adapter extends from `ListAdapter` and contains the method `submitList(List<V> items)`, which is called every time a new result is fetched.

And of course, the XML of the `RecyclerView` and its parent is `match_parent`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_fragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_swipe_refresh"
            style="@style/Container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/my_files_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:scrollbars="none"/>

...
```

The question is, why the width of the *RecyclerView* is 0 when we create it?
Are there any way to force the recycler view to be redrawn?

Note: We have also detected that, if the user rotates the phone the list is loaded correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40550327/getwidth-getheight-returning-0-inside-recyclerview-fragment

Comment: @buzzingsilently maybe related, but the items inside the view does not depend on the width of it. I use the width for an image, but there's also texto inside every item.